# Warning: 1 rules skipped due to selector errors: legend + * -> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have this warning since i've upgraded from Angular v8 to Angular v13 and bootstrap from v5.0 to v5.2 , everytime i do ctrl+s the compilation si so slow and this warning appears again 
this is the dependecies in my package.json file

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.11",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0-beta1",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.8.3",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "feather": "0.0.6",
    "feather-icons": "^4.29.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.3.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~6.3.20",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "npm": "^8.12.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, but I was able to eliminate this warning by adding the following configuration properties into the "production" build settings in the "angular.json" file:

```
            "optimization": {
              "scripts": true,
              "styles": {
                "minify": true,
                "inlineCritical": false
                },
              "fonts": true
            },
            "outputHashing": "all",
            "sourceMap": false,
            "namedChunks": false,
            "aot": true,
            "extractLicenses": true,
            "vendorChunk": false,
            "buildOptimizer": true
```

(Note: You might need only some of them in your project to solve your problem)

Comment: In my case, `"inlineCritical": false` specifically fixed the error.

Answer (score 5):

#### CSR: Client-side Rendering

In this mode, open **angualr.json** and add the following section:

**NOTE**: Path is ( **projects** > **YOUR_PROJECT_NAME** > **architect** > **build** > **configurations** > **production** )

```
"optimization": {
    "scripts": true,
    "styles": {
        "minify": true,
        "inlineCritical": false
    }
}
```

#### SSR: Server-side Rendering (Angular Universal)

Adding `optimization` section in **angualr.json** file does not work in **SSR mode(Universal)**. That's why, open the **server.ts** file(in the root of your project) and modify `ngExpressEngine` like the following:

```
ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
    inlineCriticalCss: false,
})
```

#### UPDATED

**In Angular 17+**, open **server.ts** and add `inlineCriticalCss: false` to `render function`

```
  server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap: AppServerModule,
        inlineCriticalCss: false, <---- this line.
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: browserDistFolder,
        providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl }],
      })
      .then((html) => res.send(html))
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  });
```

Comment: awesome. Perfect. thank you for the last answer

Comment: by changing in angular.json and re-run the application I am getting same warning twice!

Answer (score 4):

The warning is actually the result of a bug in the package [`critters`](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/critters), used by Angular. For more details, see https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/critters/issues/103

Answer (score 3):

In the angular.json file write the following code, under "production".

```
"optimization": {
    "scripts": true,
    "styles": {
        "minify": true,
        "inlineCritical": false
    },
    "fonts": true
},
```

Which will be also found in development. (helped by Kevin)

Answer (score 0):

To extend [PowerKiKi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73275333/10827339):

To fix this for now you can (temporarily) override the version of `css-select` (a dependency of critters, which is causing the issue) with npm, add the below snippet to `package.json` and do `npm install` and you should find it'll override the dependency.

```json
{
   ...
   "overrides": {
       "css-select": "^4.2.1"
       // Below may be optional, check the versions present in your package-lock.json, 
       // if they're already this version or later no need to include
       "css-what": "^5.1.0"
       "domhandler": "^4.3.1"
   }
   ...
}
```

(If you're using yarn, it's similar. Refer to this PR comment: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/critters/pull/117#issuecomment-1324699091)

Make sure you remove this override once a proper fix is out, keep an eye on PR 117 linked above, Angular should be updated to use a newer release at some point.

(Note that I've got Angular 15.0.1, Typescript 4.8.4 and Bootstrap 5.2.3 installed)

Proof:

[image]